# How to post a new event to office 365 calendar from php using api

Tags: php, office365

I was able to get the events from O365 calendar using https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Calendar/Events api. I would like to post an event I am creating in my calendar to office 365 calendar. How can I do that?

I tried to post, to the same url passing the parameters. But it is not getting inserted.

Any help appreciated.

Regards

Hi I was able to fix this.

I send in headers conent-type:application/json;odata.metadata=full and accept:application/json it worked.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the request and response you are getting?

Comment: Hi Rohit, When I tried through postman this is what I got,  "code": "ErrorInvalidRequest",  "message": "Cannot read the request body.".  I am not sure about what all I need to send to post.

Comment: Nice. Looks like you figured it out.